# css theme libraries

Tags: css, web, twitter-bootstrap

Are there any other css theme libraries that are similar to bootstrap twitter css?

they should offer:

- styling of every element
- extras such as alert boxes

Comment: what exactly do you mean to ask here by your question. You want a free spoon feed for your work..  ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think Bootstrap is kind of special. if you look for something similar, maybe you should give a try to Blueprint (http://blueprintcss.org/)